# Making Favorites in Finder collapse according to number of items in it

Tags: macos, finder

I know favorites can collapse completely but how possible is it to make a dropdown collapse inside the Favorites itself so that when the items reach about 5, it automatically hides all others with a dropdown arrow for seeing the others?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html